# encontrar palabra en un archivo por contains java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Hola como están gente una duda que quería hacerles.

Pasa que estoy leyendo un archivo, tengo un vector que tiene muchas palabras que debo buscar en un archivo, pero al usar contains, pasa que lo que hace es buscar las similitudes.

Y al menos en mi vector tengo la palabra REAL y si el archivo tiene la palabra LONGREAL me marca como similited porque dicha palabra termina en REAL.

Sucede que las líneas del archivo también pueden contener otras cosas por lo que es muy difícil trabajar con los indices.

**entonces quería saber si alguno sabe de algún método que me ayude a buscar palabras exactas que no sea equals porque como menciono en el archivo una misma línea puede contener otras cosas.**

Entonces allí el problema que por un lado el contains me sirve porque va a analizar toda la línea, pero no ocupo que saque coincidencias, por letras, no sé si tienen alguna sugerencia para buscar coincidencias mas exactas.

```java
if (tokensAnalisar.contains(palabrasReservadasLibelula[i])) {
nuevoArchivo.print(" no se pueden escribir palabras reservadas" + "\n");
 }
```

Comment: Utiliza expresiones regulares

Comment: no porque tiene que ser algo mucho más dinámico yo leo el archivo y comparo cada palabra del archivo con un vector que tiene 30 palabras, con una expresión regular no podría, lo que mencione era un ejemplo simple

Comment: ocupo algo como constrain pero que a la vez no me tire true porque encontró una letra porque dos palabras tenían la misma letra

Comment: Hola Esther, podrías subir una muestra del archivo sobre el que realizas la busqueda?... si este es tipo "cuento", podrías realizar la búsqueda usando tres variables por cada palabra a buscar: **contains( " " + palabrasReservadasLibelula[i] + " " ) || contains( " " + palabrasReservadasLibelula[i] + "," ) || contains( " " + palabrasReservadasLibelula[i] + "." )**. de esta forma, busca la palabra pero que esté precedida de un espacio, y seguida de un espacio, una coma o un punto.

Comment: ¿`containsAll`? Fijate si este artículo te sirve https://www.baeldung.com/string-contains-multiple-words

Comment: @EstherPorta Ademas de saber si el vector de palabras contiene la palabra que buscas, necesitas saber en que indice está? Por ejemplo buscar la palabra "REAL" que no esté junto como "LONGREAL" y ademas saber en que indice empieza y en que cual termina? O solo necesitas saber si contiene la palabra? Que pasaría si en la misma linea existe dos veces la palabra "REAL"?

Comment: Si la palabra REAL está al principio de la linea en el texto? En este caso no tendrá un espacio al principio. Si la ultima linea solo contiene la palabra REAL? Es este caso no contendrá ningún espacio.

Comment: @MarcePuente ya me ayudo muchas gracias a todos por las sujerencias

Comment: @JFrame, tenes razón, no lo había pensado, gracias por la observación!, se puede agregar **contains(  " " + palabrasReservadasLibelula[i] + "\n" )** para el final, para el principio no se me ocurre nada.

Comment: @MarcePuente Expresiones regulares. Las clases Matcher y Pattern pueden buscar cada una de las sugerencias sin problemas con pequeña expresión, ademas de que te pueden decir donde empieza y termina cada coincidencia sin necesidad de agregar algo mas. Creo que es el mejor enfoque realmente.

Comment: @JFrame, seguramente tenés razón, lo que me pasa es que cuando son muy complicadas, prefiero usar otros métodos porque no tengo un gran dominio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como no has explicado si solo quieres contar las palabras o si quieres encontrar ademas en que posición se encuentran, mostraré métodos para las dos cosas, y explicaré el enfoque con expresiones regulares.

La expresión regular que necesitas para no incluir las palabras que están juntas como **LONGREAL** es:

```
(?<!\S)REAL(?!\w)
```

#### Explicación

En la parte de `(?<!\S)` se esta diciendo primeramente que se realice una búsqueda negativa hacia atrás o *negative lookbehind*. Y lo que hace aquí es que la palabra **REAL** no puede estar precedida por otro carácter que no sea un un espacio en blanco o el principio de linea.

Y en la parte de `(?!\w)` al final es una expresión de tipo *negative lookahead* que busca una posición de la cadena que no esté seguida de ningún caracter o palabra `\w`. Mira esto para entender las búsquedas de tipo [Lookahead y Lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Con esto puedes puedes darte cuenta que la palabra **REAL** debe empezar al principio de linea o estar seguida de un espacio, "REAL" o " REAL" pero ademas no puede estar seguida de ninguna letra o numero. Es decir que **excluye** a las palabras que contienen *REAL* como parte de si, en este caso LONGREAL o REALLONG.

Puedes ver un ejemplo de esta expresión regular desde https://regex101.com/r/HCX9LU/1 que incluye el texto que utilice para probar la expresión en los métodos que te enseño a continuación.

---

#### Contar palabras

Para contar las palabras puedes hacer un método donde le puedas pasar la palabra clave que quieres buscar, y segundo el texto en el que quieres buscar la palabra:

```
private static int contarPalabra(String text, String word) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)"+word+"(?!\\w)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    int counter = 0;

    while(matcher.find()) {
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Eso tiene un contador que en cada coincidencia incrementa +1, finalmente devuelve el total de veces que aparece la palabra. Si es 0 significa que no se encuentra la palabra, por lo que puedes utilizarlo como `boolean` en un if.

---

#### Contar palabras y obtener posiciones

Si ademas quieres saber en que posiciones se encuentran cada una, puedes hacer lo mismo pero creando una linea con una matriz, la matriz guarda las posiciones de inicio y de fin de la palabra.

```
private static List<int[]> encontrarPalabraReservada(String texto, String palabraReservada) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)" + palabraReservada + "(?!\\w)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

    List<int[]> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

    while(matcher.find()) {
        indexes.add(new int[] {
            matcher.start(),
            matcher.end()
        });
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Esto devuelve una lista que contiene matrices que guardan la posición de inicio y de fin de cada una de las palabras. Para saber donde empieza puede hacer `[0]` y cuando termina `[1]`. Ademas de que puedes saber cuantas veces se repitió la palabra mediante un simple `.size()` de la lista.

---

#### Como usar

Para utilizar el método para contar cuantas veces se repite la palabra puedes hacer esto:

```
File file = new File("archivo.txt");
String texto = Files.readString(file.toPath());
System.out.println(contarPalabra(texto, "REAL"));
```

Si quieres saber cuantas veces se repite la palabra reservada y ademas saber las posiciones en las que se encuentran puedes hacer esto:

```
File file = new File("archivo.txt");
String texto = Files.readString(file.toPath());
        
List<int[]> palabrasReservadas = encontrarPalabraReservada(texto, "REAL");

palabrasReservadas.forEach(palabrasReservada -> {
    System.out.println(
        "Se ha encontrado una palabra reservada en la posición: %d, %d."
        .formatted(palabrasReservada[0], palabrasReservada[1])
    );
});
```

Por cada palabra imprime su posición de inicio y de fin. Por ejemplo:

```
Se ha encontrado una palabra reservada en la posición: 0, 4.
Se ha encontrado una palabra reservada en la posición: 40, 44.
Se ha encontrado una palabra reservada en la posición: 195, 199.
Se ha encontrado una palabra reservada en la posición: 279, 283.
```

Los indices te pueden servir si quieres ir accediendo a subcadenas:

```
System.out.println(texto.substring(0, 4));
System.out.println(texto.substring(40, 44));
System.out.println(texto.substring(195, 199));
```

**Nota**: He utilizado los métodos `Files.readString` y `String.formatted` que están disponibles a partir de Java 11 y 15 para leer el texto del archivo, esto es únicamente para dar un inicio rápido a los que quieren probar el código, pero por lo que he visto tu ya tienes un método para leer el texto.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

No es que sea "cabezota", es que mientras no haya un alma caritativa que suba el regex adecuado... dejo este engendro.

```
boolean contiene( String palabra, String texto ) {
   if( texto.contains( palabra ) && largoTexto == largoPalabra
          || ( inicio == 0 && texto.contains( palabra + " " )
                           || texto.contains( palabra + "," )
                           || texto.contains( palabra + "." ) )
          || texto.contains( " " + palabra ) && inicio + largoPalabra == largoTexto
          || texto.contains( " " + palabra + " " )
          || texto.contains( " " + palabra + "," )
          || texto.contains( " " + palabra + "." ) ) {
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Y si dejamos un engendro... porque no dos?.

```
boolean buscar( String palabra, String texto ) {
   int inicio = texto.indexOf( palabra );
   if( inicio == -1 ) {
      return false;
   }
   if( texto.length() == palabra.length() ) {
      return true;
   }
   int fin = palabra.length() + inicio;
   if( inicio == 0 && ( texto.substring( fin - 1, fin ) ).matches( "[a-zA-Z]" ) ) {
      return true;
   }
   if( inicio + palabra.length() == texto.length() && !( texto.substring( inicio - 1, inicio ) ).matches( "[a-zA-Z]" ) ) {
      return true;
   }
   return !( texto.substring( fin, fin + 1 ) ).matches( "[a-zA-Z]" ) && !( texto.substring( inicio - 1, inicio ) ).matches( "[a-zA-Z]" );
}
```

Este método encuentra ***"hola"*** en ***"siempre decir hola, antes"*** y también encuentra ***"hola"*** en ***"siempre decir hola?"***, o ***"0hola&2"***, dicho de otra manera, encuentra letras rodeadas de ***no-letras***.

Comment: En todo caso hazlo a lreves. A la linea que leas del archivo la partes en palabras  con un split y  por cada palabra la buscas en tu vector con un contains, es decir, si la palabra está contenida en tu vector, con eso no tendrá el problema actual porque ahora estas buscando las palabras de la linea de texto en tu vector. El contains cambia, en vez de buscar tu vector en la linea , haces que cada palabra de linea se busque en tu vector.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!